# autocomplete style

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete input, but when I prompt something, the legend which says

> "... results are available"

is shown just near the input, so the page looks bad :(.
how to move this legend to the right for any amount of pixels I can set?

here is piece of code:

```
$("#myAutocomplete").autocomplete
    ({ 
        source: res,
        position: {  my: "left+250 top" },
        minLength: 1
    });
```

documentation seems to have no answers :(

here is res object(for example):

```
var res = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
```

Comment: which CSS are you using for it? jquery default? or maybe it isnt even included that is why it displays like that?

Comment: I included such files: `<script
 src="/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"/>"`, `<script src="/js/jquery.js"/>"`

Comment: Yes thats for JS, did you include their css file too?

Comment: thats the only reason im sure :)  add jquery CSS file too

Comment: look the comment in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: yes, it looks different now, but I need the legend, which is to the right and says "n results are available"

Comment: can you create a fiddle and we can see it?

Comment: just don't include css and you'll have the same result :) fiddle will take too much time

Comment: I have client-server app, so it would really take too much time to show the result. but not including css will give the same result as I have for now

Comment: ok can you please paste the code which contains javascript object "res" so i can check in same scenario as in your code. as your code mentions "res" as source of data for autocomplete

Comment: it's a ajax response, which contains json object, but you can see the question update